# ROHM AC zero cross chip/circuit not working

Tags: circuit-design, zero-crossing

I'm using the ROHM chip [BM1Z003FJ](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/power/isolated_converter/bm1z002fj-e.pdf) to detect AC zero cross and send that pulse to the micro, the only problem is the ROHM chip never outputs a pulse.

My circuit is shown below:

[image]

The ACOUT pin should pulse every time the AC (just using 120 V/60 Hz wall) crosses zero, but I'm getting nothing.  I'm seeing the same waveforms at pins 6 and 7 using my circuit and the ROHM demo board for this part, but the demo board outputs properly.

In the data sheet (and their demo board) they show a full bridge rectifier which produces the supply voltage for their chip, but don't say anywhere that thid is required for the zero cross functionality.

I'm wondering, however, if the rectified "GND" needs to be there, tied to pin 3 to give a proper reference for pins 6 and 7?

Data sheet circuit:

[image]

Comment: The GND issue looks like something you should try also why do you have 100 ohm resistors after the diodes in VH_AC1/2? I don't see that in their datasheet.

Comment: Good question, I think the engineer that first designed this copied the demo board for the most part and they had those.  Pin protection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

D1 & D2 are necessary to "gnd" for this ZCS IC.  These complete the circuit with your D26, D27 with less than 40 uA.